# WebKitMutationObserver can't observe <link> tag

Tags: mutation-observers

**TLDR:** Why the observer is not triggered?

I'm trying to capture the favicon changes. Let's see my observer:

```
var observer = new window.WebKitMutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    console.log(mutations);
});

// All config as `true` in case of...
observer.observe(document.querySelector('head link[rel*="icon"]'), {
    attributes: true,
    childList : true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true
});
```

There is no `console.log()` triggered, the observer doesn't like the `head link[rel*="icon"]` selector, even this selector is correct. If I set `head` as a selector it works but how can I know what node has been updated?

Here is my extra code to test this behavior out of the box:

```
function changeIcon (url) {
    document.querySelectorAll('head link[rel*="icon"]')[0].href = url;
}

setTimeout(function () {
    changeIcon('https://www.google.fr/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico');
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    changeIcon('https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_96-vfldSA3ca.png');
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
    changeIcon('https://abs.twimg.com/favicons/favicon.ico');
}, 3000);
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkw5585h/

Comment: It works. It's just jsfiddle being dumb. See https://output.jsbin.com/bufezusave & https://jsbin.com/bufezusave/edit?html,js